# Block RedirectTo in Exchange Online

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I am able to find lots of information online about blocking Auto-Forwarding in Exchange/Exchange Online, however I haven't been able to find a way to prevent users from forwarding email by using the Inbox Rule action RedirectTo.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have already tried many of the options listed here: [The many ways to block automatic email forwarding in Exchange Online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/The-many-ways-to-block-automatic-email-forwarding-in-Exchange/ba-p/607579)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method of transport rule in the link you provided, or set the transport rule like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, but unfortunately that doesn’t seem to work for Redirected messages. I already have that setup and it seems to be working well for forwarding...

Comment: Could you provide the redirected message's header?